# How to get CDATA from xml node using xsl and convert in a new XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

Good Morning,

I have a problem with a XML that contents CDATA code. If we have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<character>
   <Body>
      <methodResult>
         <nodeOut>
            <![CDATA[  <film>Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull</film>]]>
         </nodeOut>
      </methodResult>
   </Body>
</character>
```

We need to have this:

```
<film>Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull</film>
```

Where is the XSLT? I want extract only the CDATA content in a XML file and delete the rest. I use XSLT 1.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will produce XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- ignore this elements -->
    <xsl:template match="role|actor|part"/>

    <!-- get the remaining text and remove white-spaces -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><film>Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull</film>
```

Comment: Hi Baderous, this solution is for XSLT 2.0? I need XSLT 1.0. Thanks.

Comment: Although it says 2.0 in the template, it's backwards-compatible since it only uses 1.0 features.

Comment: I have editted my sample xml...can you review it? Sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: The result is the same. Why didn't you test it first? Use something like Oxygen to create the XSLT and apply the transformation to the XML.

Comment: I test with http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html and not works. Thanks you.

Comment: Well, this error message is simply useless: "Unable to perform XSL transformation on your XML file. null". Which XSLT processor is that tool using? My recommendation is that you forget about that online tool and use Oxygen where you can choose between different XSLT processors and it is a great tool. You can ask for a trial key to use it. And please stop changing your initial XML! It's the 3rd XML you paste. Even so, my XSLT still works with it (transformer: Saxon-HE 9.6.0.7).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a transformation that has the output method set to `text` and simply extract the text node from the `name` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template select="name/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will fail if there's multiple CDATA sections in the element, that you'd need to create some sort of root element if there's more than one `name` in your input. There's also leading whitespace in your CDATA section so I suggest you trim the output. One way you could do that in the XSLT itself is to use function `normalize-space()` but it would affect the contents of the CDATA "xml" as well. There's also no XML prolog with this method, so if the output is seen as valid XML depends on what you feed it to.

But this is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks G_H but I need a XML for output method. This solution is not valid for me :(  I need:  <xsl:output method="xml" />

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution is possible in XSLT 3.0 (as supported by Saxon 9.7 or Exselt) using

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml-fragment(character/name/text()[last()])"/>
</xsl:template>
```

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml-fragment.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot to comment that I use XSLT 1.0. Thanks